# Mark item when it's selected

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am starting to learn asp.net and I am a totally noob.

So, I am trying to select a town and, in the right side I should get the list of all town (like in the picture above).

So I am trying to do like, when I select a town from left side it should be mark as selected as from the right side.

[image]

My code is below

```
<table class="table datatable-responsive datatable-medical-map" id="medProviders" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-info">
            <th>Medical Provider (* Choose one)</th>
            <th>Distance (miles)</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @{  int i = 0;

            foreach (var item in medProviders)
            {
                <tr class="sortList" style="cursor:pointer" id="increment-@i" data-id="@item.Id" data-lat="@item.Latitude" data-long="@item.Longitude">

                    <td>@item.Firstname</td>
                    <td id="distance-@i"></td>
                    <td id="duration-@i"></td>

                </tr>

                i++;
            }
        }

    </tbody>
</table>

<p id="medicalValidation"></p>
```

Comment: Can you add the picture?

Comment: Yes, here it is

Comment: Read [ask] and define "mark as selected". What does that mean, exactly? Is it applying a CSS class, or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I am new here

Comment: If mark as selected means showing a background color then you'll have to use client side scripting (jquery/ javascrip) to add and remove class for table tr's.

Comment: When I select for example from left side New York, it should be marked

Comment: Usually you have a ComboBox, where each dispaly string equals a number(selectedValue). And then the "selectedValue" is what you want. Usually you build the ComboBox contents from something like a DatabaseQuery or Constant values (Enumeration). That way each number equate exactly one value and vice versa.

Comment: Also you should propably stop using that inline style. Do proper Code behind programming for what you want.

Comment: I know for ComoBox, but I am asking for data-datable option.
As you can see from the picture

Comment: What you're asking for isn't impossible, but I wanted to make some notes about your UI intentions: Would it not be better if the list on the right only showed entries from the selected town and hid the others from sight; as opposed to merely marking the entries from the select town?